# How to define your own Windows 8 App Theme?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

For a school assignement I'm doing some basic research on how Windows 8 Store App Development works. I followed [the Hello World tutorial provided by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx). The main themes you can use for the app are Light and Dark (and if I'm correct there's a third one High Contrast or something?), these are defined by MS.

My question is, how can I create my own theme? I'd like to have a basic App Theme with the two main colours defined by me. I think this would be possible, but I haven't found any way of doing it. Looked here on stackoverflow, but didn't find anything helpful (most mention files and such not present in the simple Hello World app).

In short: is it possible to create a theme for you Windows 8 app (mainly choosing the foreground and background colours), comparable to the standard provided Dark and Light themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best off using a resource dictionary to hold information on your custom styles.

<s>(This is a WPF example, I'm assuming it's the same for apps, if not, let me know).</s>

In your `App.xaml`, add a merged dictionary, so your App.xaml may look something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/CoreStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You will then need to create a resource dictionary (in my example, I put it in Style/CoreStyle.xaml)

You can then style individual elements in your project, for example, setting a `minwidth` on a button will look something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

There is a lot more information on the [MSDN Styling and Templating Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which I'd recommend reading.

Comment: Okay, looks good, I'm gonna try it out. Thanks! Dumb question: how do I create a Resource dictionary in such a .xaml file? Just between <ResourceDictionary></ResourceDictionary> tags? EDIT: Found it, it was a template when adding a new item!

Comment: If you're using VS, you can just add a new file of type resource dictionary. I'll update my answer with the full file template though

Comment: Thanks! I now have the ResourceDictionary defined, but how do I tell an element it has to get it's style from this ResourceDictionary? I have a simple style in the RD with just a background colour for a Grid. How can I tell the grid in my layout xaml that it has to use that style?

Comment: Make sure you merge the dictionary (the first part of the xaml). As long as there is no key specified, and the target type is set to `Grid`, it should just work.

Comment: When I put the code you provided in my App.xaml, it gives a blue wiggly line underneath the second tag (ResourceDictionary) telling me each Resource Dictionary needs an associated key.

Comment: Ah never mind there was a style i defined individually above it which had a key, I commented it and everything seems to be working now! Thanks a lot for your time Joe, I'll mark yours as the answer!

Comment: @E.V.d.B. There is also something called [ThemeDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.themedictionaries.Aspx) in Windows 8 app development. If I get chance this week, I'll update my answer with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

WP8 default gives you only 2 themes Dark and Light, So If you need to create a theme other than that I think It's not possible.

But if you need to apply theme for a application It's possible, But you have to write all the styles for your theme.

Comment: Yeah I would actually just like to apply other colours. It can be the default theme, with just different colours, but I have no idea how I can do this. (I know how XAML works, I just don't where I can change it.) There's no StandardStyles.xaml in my Common folder, because I'm using VS 2013 and I read it isn't present anymore. Could I just change an existing style, and if so: how?

Comment: You have so many options to create some styles in your application.
1). You can add colors and other setting to your controls using controls properties.
2). Application Resources
3). Page Resources

Here a Example for a Page Resource
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Gold"/>
    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="PageBackground">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource PageBackground}">
    </Border>
</StackPanel>